# Linq 2 SQL Join/Group with count

Tags: linq-to-sql

I had to modify a query to add an additional join to bring in a Division name.

```
            var c = from C in db.Campaigns
                join L in db.Links on C.id equals L.campaignID into CL
                from CL2 in CL.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join D in db.Divisions on CL2.divisionID equals D.id into CLD
                from CLD2 in CLD.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where C.ClientID == user.ClientID
                group CLD2 by new { C.id, C.Name, Division = CLD2.Name, C.created } into G
                select new {
                    CampaignName = G.Key.Name,
                    Campaignid = G.Key.id,
                    Division = G.Key.Division ?? "-",
                    Created = G.Key.created,
                    Links = G.Count(b => b.Name != null) };
```

The problem I'm having with it is that the Division name is empty for each row when the count of links is 0 (and it shouldn't be).

So I tried to write it a different way using Lambda:

`var c =
                from CLD in
                (
                    from C in db.Campaigns
                    from L in db.Links.Where(w => w.campaignID == C.id).DefaultIfEmpty()
                    from D in db.Divisions.Where(w => w.id == C.DivisionID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where C.ClientID == user.ClientID
                    select new
                    {
                        CampaignName = C.Name,
                        Campaignid = C.id,
                        Division = D.Name,
                        Created = C.created
                    }
                )
                group CLD by new { id = CLD.Campaignid, Name = CLD.CampaignName, Division = CLD.Division, created = CLD.Created } into G
                select new { CampaignName = G.Key.Name, Campaignid = G.Key.id, Division = G.Key.Division ?? "-", Created = G.Key.created, Links = G.Count(b => b.Campaignid != null) };`

In this query, the Division names appear correctly for all rows but when the count of Links is 0, the query returns 1 instead.

I'm confident that I'm close in both cases, but can't seem to find the right syntax.  Any suggestions welcome.  Happy to have a fix for either query but would love to eventually see how to address both.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got someone to look at it and help me sort it out.  This is a much more concise query and more fully lambda than my second one which was more of a messy hybrid.  So hopefully this example may help someone else down the road.

```
         var x = db.Campaigns.Where(w => w.ClientID == user.ClientID)
        .GroupJoin(db.Divisions, c => c.DivisionID, d => d.id, (c, d) => new { cmp = c, Division = d.FirstOrDefault().Name })
        .GroupJoin(db.Links, cdl => cdl.cmp.id, l => l.campaignID, (cdl, l) => new { cdl.cmp, cdl.Division, Links = l.Count() })
        .ToList()
        .Select(s => new
        {
            CampaignName = s.cmp.Name,
            Campaignid = s.cmp.id,
            Division = s.Division ?? "-",
            Created = s.cmp.created,
            Links = s.Links
        });
```